# SyncDB after installing new app having already installed South - don't want to mess anything up

Tags: mysql, django, django-south, sorl-thumbnail, syncdb

I'm using South to manage my (MySQL) database tables for a Django 1.4 project, its working great.

This is a bit of a newbie question, but I'm now adding sorl.thumbnail (http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installation) to the list of installed apps in the settings file.

The instructions say that I now have to use syncdb if I'm using a "cached database key value store".

Is it OK to go ahead and use syncdb? I'm not quite sure if my MySQL+South installation counts as one. Will this mess anything up?

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong, when you start using south you should never use syncdb again. Instead, you should use `schemamigration` or other south's specific commands.

[Here](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#schemamigration) you can find what you were looking for. I quote here the phrase that should clear your mind:

> The main use of schemamigration is when you’ve just finished your shiny new models.py and want to load up your database. In vanilla Django, you’d just run syncdb - however, with migrations, you’ll need a migration to create the tables.
>
> In this scenario, you just run:
>
> ./manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
>
> That will write one big migration to create all the tables for the
> models in your app; just run ./manage.py migrate to get it in and
> you’re done in only one more step than syncdb!

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm sorry @lciamp. I didn't see your answer when i posted mine. If it bothers you, i can delete it and edit your post, or comment your post to add a link to south documentation. Nevertheless, i read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122411/deleting-an-answer-as-others-poured-the-same-quickly) and think that it is not wrong to post a simmilar answer... i see this all the time here and nobody complains about that.... But again, if you think i'm wrong and give me your point of view, i delete my post and try to add this information in another way....

Comment: sorry for being a dick. I was in a bad mood last night. I went through your profile and up-voted all your correct answers. Sorry again ;)

Comment: ;) no problem... thanks for your honesty... we all have bad days, and sometimes we get ungry with the wrong person... cheers!

Answer (score -2):

syncdb does not interfere with South, in fact, in order to install a new app you should always use syncdb first, then apply south for migrations if you have any. So, yes, you are not going to have any problem.